# Import data from one excel file to another

Tags: excel-formula

I have had some code that has been working really well for me for ages. It searches for and imports data from other files.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(1,INDEX((INT('November-2017.csv'!A$2:A$10000)=A107925)*('November-2017.csv'!L$2:L$10000=K107925),),0)),"",INDEX('November-2017.csv'!P$2:P$100000,MATCH(1,INDEX((INT('November-2017.csv'!A$2:A$10000)=A107925)*('November-2017.csv'!L$2:L$10000=K107925),),0)))
```

All I have ever needed to do is copy the formula into a cell, change the filename and relevant column and/or row references and the data imports into that cell; then I simply copy and paste it right down the destination column and it imports the data. Sometimes I have to increase the range as some source files have more than 10000 rows. The data has always been imported into the same file which has 10 or so different tabs. To avoid the file requesting to be updated all the time, I copy each of the columns and then paste the data back in as values. I merely leave the code in each column right at the top, so I have it handy to copy when needed.

But I have been trying to do the same today into a new file and cannot get it to import anything at all. The code has not changed; only the destination file. The new destination file is an Excel file .xls rather than a .csv file, but can't see that has any bearing on it. The source file has less than 10000 rows, making that all fine; the cell I am pasting into is row 107924 in the destination file.  The date is column A and matches perfectly, the name in the source file is in column L and in the destination file it is column K; they also both match. The data I require is in column P in the source file. So everything looks fine to me and it still works if I import data into the file I have always imported into, yet the new destination cell remains blank.

When I try pasting the code into the file I have been using most of the time and change the relevant column and row references, it works fine.

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(1,INDEX((INT('November-2017.csv'!A$2:A$10000)=A3)*('November-2017.csv'!L$2:L$10000=D3),),0)),"",INDEX('November-2017.csv'!P$2:P$10000,MATCH(1,INDEX((INT('November-2017.csv'!A$2:A$10000)=A3)*('November-2017.csv'!L$2:L$10000=D3),),0)))
```

The only differences appear to be in the row to check the date (new file date is in A107925 vs A3) and the column and row to check the name (new file is K107925 vs D3).

Any help gladly accepted, as it is doing my head in.

cheers

Shane

Comment: Oh, the file I am importing data from is a .csv file, but the destination file is a .xlsx file. Could this be the issue? if so, how to facilitate the import?

Comment: On further investigation, the link between the source and destination files seems to be the culprit. Normally when you close the source file, you see the full location of it appear in the code above. Then when you reopen the source, it reverts to the shortened version you see above. This is not happening and I don't know why